# Spring MVC (xml config nightmare?) vs spring roo?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am just delving into the spring mvc (or spring roo), from what i have read it appears that spring MVC can be a nightmare to configure. I have to configure XML files, is this the web.xml file??? Or something different?

Is it still a nightmare or has it been improved?

Is there no editor for these XML files? I am using eclipse IDE

Spring roo apparently does spring mvc without XML config worries.

I would love anyone to explain the differences..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First Spring MVC is not a nightmare to configure, you just have to know what you are doing.

For that I would suggest you to download Spring IDE, which have a lot of XML editors that make you life easier if you are not experienced with Spring XMLs.

Basicly you have to configure 2 things

- Web.xml ( this one is not because of spring it's Java EE, but you
  need to include some spring MVC configs in it )
- applicationContext.xml( this is where you define what you want from Spring )
- servlet-context.xml ( this is also from spring MVC and have some servlet definitions as well as some routing ones)

one you get to know them you will find it easy to configure and very flexible.

One thing to notice Spring and Spring MVC are different things, I advise you to learn both of them.

Also Spring Roo is a code generator, for Cruds, simple things and setup projects it's great but if you need to build a reasonable big app that will need support it's always easier to create everything youself because it's easier to support when you know the code, so use it with care.

Comment: Thanks, the spring ide, this is eclipse right? with the spring plugin? I was just about to download that... if thats the same thing

Comment: There is a plugin for eclipse, but there is one that is a complete solution not a plugin it's build on top of eclipse but it's not eclipse. It's nice if you pretend to work with the Spring pack

Comment: Maybe you can use Spring Tool Suite if you want. I am using it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add that Spring XML configuration can be as simple as a few lines, with the bulk of work done via annotations. It may not always be *preferable* to do it that way, but it's an option. Configuration can be divided between mechanisms when it makes sense to do so.

You might want to spend some time with the Spring documentation, at least regarding the components you're using. If you think configuring it is a nightmare, wait until you have to diagnose a problem brought about by magic based on convention without understanding how the underlying framework(s) work.